# Having trouble identifying keypress using msvcrt

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, msvcrt, pyhook

I have been trying to receive input in a way that won't stuck my program (`msvcrt` instead of recv). Yet, my program isn't working and I'm having trouble understanding why.

I tried writing a code (that somehow works on my friend's computer, but not on mine).

```
import msvcrt

print ("enter something")

line = b""
while True:
  ch = msvcrt.getwch()
  print "2"
  if ch == b'\r':
    print (line.decode('latin-1'))
    break

  line = line + ch
  print (ch.decode('latin-1'))
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: `msvcrt.getwch` reads input directly from the console of a process. It does not read from `sys.stdin`, so it will not work in an IDE or any other environment that doesn't use a console, such as an MSYS2 terminal (e.g. git-bash).